# Check xslt case?

Tags: xslt

I have a xslt

```
<category numberofproducts="0">
  <id>Main</id>
  <url>/products/Main</url>
  <name>Main</name>
  <texts>
    <text language="standard">
      <name>Name</name>
      <longdescription></longdescription>
      <shortdescription></shortdescription>
      <htmltitle></htmltitle>
      <metadescription></metadescription>
      <metakeywords></metakeywords>
    </text>
  </texts>
  <name>Kopipapir</name>
  <longdescription></longdescription>
  <shortdescription></shortdescription>
  <htmltitle></htmltitle>
  <metadescription></metadescription>
  <metakeywords></metakeywords>
  <category numberofproducts="47">
    <id>Name1</id>
    <url>/products/Name1</url>
    <name>Name1, New</name>
    <texts>
      <text language="standard">
        <name>New, Nmae</name>
        <longdescription></longdescription>
        <shortdescription></shortdescription>
        <htmltitle></htmltitle>
        <metadescription></metadescription>
        <metakeywords></metakeywords>
      </text>
    </texts>
   </category>
  <category numberofproducts="23">
    <id>Name2</id>
    <url>/products/Name2</url>
    <name>Name2, hvd</name>
    <texts>
      <text language="standard">
        <name>Name2, hvd</name>
        <longdescription></longdescription>
        <shortdescription></shortdescription>
        <htmltitle></htmltitle>
        <metadescription></metadescription>
        <metakeywords></metakeywords>
      </text>
    </texts>
   </category>
```

I need to check there is category in category

I tried something like..

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$ccat/category//category != '' ">

          <xsl:text >Category</xsl:text>

      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Listing</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Anyone help?

Comment: And what exactly your problem is? IMO it should work in this way. Just mention you are not testing presence of category element but the string value of pertinent "category" child element.

Comment: I need to check the category  is present inside the category.if it is the do some thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer below, assumption is you wish to check for the existence of any category child under category root

```
<xsl:if test="boolean(/category//category)='true'">
    <xsl:text>Category</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Or shortly: `<xsl:if test="/category//category">`.

Comment: Sure. I just like to be explicit (when coding :)